# Python Pandas - Match values in two series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search two datasets to see if an entry in one dataset is entered anywhere in another.
The datasets I have are imported as .csv files with the following shapes;

```
dfA.shape =
(500, 4)

dfB.shape =
(900, 2)
```

The data I am comparing is the last column in each dataframe. I would like to know if an entry in dfA is entered anywhere in dfB. My objective is to have a dataframe (say dfC) with all the matches in.
I have checked the types of each with dtypes which come back as “object”.
I am trying to do something like;

```
for i in range(len(dfA)):

   for j in range(len(dfB))

        if dfA.LastCol[i] == dfB.LastCol[j]:

            q = dfA.LastCol[i]
            dfC = dfC.append(q)
```

dfC would then hold the results of the matches.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "in" method. This will search for all the values in the second Series and will return true if there is a match

```
for i in range(len(dfA)):

   for j in range(len(dfB)):
        

        if dfA.LastCol[i].values in  dfB.values:

            q = dfA.LastCol[i]
            dfC = dfC.append(q)
```

You can tweak the if condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join, it will give you the entire data-set aswell.
key: whatever is the last col in both the dataframes

```
pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='inner', on="key")
```

Make sure that key or the last col_name is same in both the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pandas merge?

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['val1', 'val7', 'val3', 'val5'],
                    'B': [1, 7, 3, 5]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'],
                    'D': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

dfC = dfA.merge(dfB, left_on='B', right_on='D')

print(dfC)
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can do this:

```
list_A = dfA.iloc[:,-1]

list_B = dfB.iloc[:,-1]

dfC = set(list_A).intersection(list_B)

print(dfC)
```